# <a> href not opening the replaced href

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I am building a youtube chrome extension.
I am trying to replace href of `<a>` tag  which is

```
<a class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-compact-video-renderer"></a> .
```

Which is html dom i want to trigger after i change href

in **js** i have

```
var ele =  document.getElementsByClassName( "yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-compact-video-renderer" )[0];

ele.setAttribute('href' ,"watch?v=Rj2QkLaaj2E");

ele =  document.getElementsByClassName( "yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-compact-video-renderer" )[0];


 ele.click();
```

I changed href of ele and triggered click() but it is opening old href instead of replaced one.

Comment: Are you sure you are targeting the element you want and not another one sharing same classes ?

Comment: yes i check that

Comment: Hmmm it is weird because I have tested it [here](https://jsbin.com/vulivusuja/edit?html) and it works.. it appends your link correctly.

Comment: it appends but on click event it opens previous link

Comment: This is a behavior for Youtube, they might be using events and not simply the href.

Comment: There's no `click()` method in the standard DOM. You need to dispatch the event: `ele.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}))`

Comment: Also, the site apparently uses a custom click handler to implement its navigation so you need to override their click handler with yours or find a better place to change href.

Comment: @wOxxOm There is [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) although it is a bit old.

Comment: @SergeK.not just old, but obsolete, and it worked only on [some elements, apparently only `<input>` as per the DOM2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-2651361).